# Yii2 Accessing another controller/view in view

Tags: yii2

what I am trying to do is like this:

```
$this->render('//article/overview'); ?>
```

The contents of `overview` is like this:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Article */

$this->title = $model->subject;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Articles'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
\yii\web\YiiAsset::register($this);
?>
<div class="article-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<div style="margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $model->contents; ?></div>
```

and the related controller code is like:

```
public function actionOverview($id=1)
    {
        return $this->render('overview', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: May-be something like: Yii::$app->runAction('article/overview', ['id' => 1]); ?

Comment: Please, give more details. Unclear what are you trying to do. Provide more code: from what view you need to access another? What controllers do you have, what actions you whant to call. You can use $this->render('view/path') inside view to render another view.

Comment: Hi @AntonRybalko - exactly as you said, if I am trying within another view with the same code that is `$this->render('view/path')` that is `$this->render('//article/overview')` but with that I am getting the error like `$model` is not defined. Please let me, which part of more code do you want to view. I have given the controller and view both.

Comment: You need to pass `model` to the view `$this->render('//article/overview', 'model' => $model)`

Comment: And before - pass `model` variable to the first view

Comment: I didn't follow your second comment, can you explain that little more. And before - pass model variable to the first view

Comment: You can't call `<?= $this->render('/article/overview'); ?>` because this view uses $model variabke `<?php echo $model->contents; ?>`. You need to pass model variable into the view like that `<?= $this->render('/article/overview', 'model' => $model); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Solved in a different way.
I will welcome, if it can be done in a simpler way.
I want to display a view from a controller on home-page of my yii2-application.

so calling view

Then I removed the above code from the `site/index.php` and updated the related contrllers i.e `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model  = Article::find()->where(['id' => 1])->one();
        return $this->render('//article/overview', [
            'model' => $this->findModel(1),
        ]);
    }
```

also added the line on top like:

```
use app\models\Article;
use app\models\ArticleSearch;
```

and added another action at the bottom of the controller:

```
protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Article::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
    }
```

But I think it should be done in a simpler way, looks like a overkill to call just a view, which is already there.